# "BIOS will skip Windows UEFI firmware update" option - how can BIOS / firmware do that?

Tags: windows, boot, bios, firmware

I was not able to find the answer via web search to meaning of that in BIOS of my PC, only rephrasing https://www.libble.eu/lenovo-thinkpad-a285/online-manual-837565/?page=0084:

> Windows UEFI Firmware Update Values: Enabled, Disabled Descriptions:
> Enable or disable the Windows UEFI Firmware Update feature. Select
> Enabled to allow  Windows UEFI Firmware Update. If you select
> Disabled, BIOS will skip Windows UEFI Firmware Update

Also [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/windows-uefi-firmware-update-platform) link. AFAIK BIOS code (UEFI Firmware) is stored in non-volatile memory that can be written to (updated). And Windows can update that code when it (Windows) runs. How can BIOS skip update if Windows replaces/updates BIOS memory contents?

Added:
I want to know technical details that would be enough to at least answer the question whether Windows can still update (say due to a bug) with that option selected (option is on a screen that is available when I select "Enter BIOS setup utility" during boot with F1 pressed on my PC with UEFI BIOS dated per its screen 2021).

Also, if not off-topic, how that option effects other operating systems.

Comment: It's actually UEFI since a decade ago. And that setting merely prevents the installation of firmware updates from Windows if one is available.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I almost guessed that, however the question is "how". If Windows writes to some NVM, how UEFI can prevent that?

Comment: I don't know the exact details but I imagine it sets something as "read only".

Comment: @ChanganAuto, The wording is like Windows gives UEFI some data (update) and UEFI decides what to do with that. But your guess for read-only is more plausible IMO.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your device has UEFI not BIOS. Windows simply downloads the firmware update and stages it or skips the download if the option is disabled. The update to the firmware would happen before the Windows boot loader takes control of the device.

Comment: @Ramhound, "windows ...skips the download". Windows still can update even with that option selected, is it correct? say due to a bug in implementation?

Comment: Windows has always treated firmware updates as optional, optional Windows Updates, are user selectable. The setting within the device's firmware, controls if the update staged by Winows, will or will not be installed